# Discord Bot on Raspbarry Pi

Tags: c#

I want to run a Discord Bot (Discord.Net) on a Raspberry Pi. The problem is, I couldn't really find anything in the Internet. Maybe someone can help me.

My Bot is written in C# and I am using a RBP 3 Model B.

What I tried:

- Installing DoNet Core on the Pi
- Trying to use WindowsIoT

Maybe I have done some mistakes, but at all, it did not work.

My knowledge about the Linux Command Line is very limited, so excuse me for that.

Thank's for the help :)

Comment: Scott describes [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/13HoursDebuggingASegmentationFaultInNETCoreOnRaspberryPiAndTheSolutionWas.aspx) some error when he tried to publish a .net core app to a raspi. Nevertheless it also describes what he used to create and run that program on the raspi.

Comment: @Oliver Thanks so much ;)